# How do I get all authors posts of a custom post type outside loop

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, post-meta, author

I'm trying to create a utility script that to add some metadata into all posts of a certain post type. Right now I have it set up to loop through all users

```
$blogusers = get_users(array(
        'role'     => 'freelancer'
));

for( $i = $index;  $i < count($blogusers); ++$i) {

    $user = $blogusers[$i];

    $userID = $user->ID; // set to user id

    $profile_id = get_user_meta( $userID, 'user_profile_id', true);

    $user_reach = get_post_meta( $profile_id, 'total_reach', true);

    $user_engagement = get_post_meta( $profile_id, 'total_starpower', true);

    $user_rating = get_post_meta( $profile_id, 'rating_score', true);

    write_log("working on " . $user->user_login);
}
```

I want to copy `user_reach`, `user_engagement`, and `user_rating` into the meta of all of the users posts of BID post type.

Comment: Do you think it's a good idea to duplicate that info to every post? Isn't it better to store that in user profile only once?

Comment: Unfortunately, its the only option I can accomplish.  
The other option is would require me to sort post order of 1 by post the meta from another post type.